# Strange layout behaviour

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I am a little bit confused. Here is a small web page.
There are two main div-s: top and mainBlock.
First contains an image. The problem is that firebug shows that div#top's height is equal to 0 and because of that the next div mainBlock moves up. If I would delete this piece of code:

```
div#logo{
    float: left;
}
```

everything will start working fine and div#mainBlock will be below the div#top. Could you, please, explain me how it works and how to avoid this in proper way?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Paralab - Website &amp; interface design, web apps development, usability</title>
<style text="text/css">
html, body{
}
div#logo{
    float: left;
}
#top{
  width: 100%;
}
#mainBlock{
  width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="top">
        <div id="logo">
            <img alt="logo"  src="img/logo.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainBlock">
        Contact Us
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your float. There are a few ways to do this, I'd check out this [article on QuirksMode about clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the article. Now I caught the point!

Answer (score 1):

because it's floating - add `clear:left;` to your `mainBlock` class.

http://jsfiddle.net/XEaBT/

Answer (score 0):

Floated images leave the flow of the document. Set #top{overflow:hidden;}

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend that you use a strict doctype instead of transitional.  You will get more consistent behavior across browsers.